# extract the first number or occurrence using regular expression in scarpy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

the html text is:

```
Tarif : 3 065 € HT 8 605 € HT forfait repas 
Tarif : 6 570 € HT
```

in this  example  i want always extract the first occurrence (3065) and ( 6 570)
this is my code:

```
training["price"] = ' '.join(response.xpath('//div[@class="product-price"]//text()').re((r'(\d+)')))
```

i tried with search but there is a mistake ? please help

Comment: Please add exactly html, not only text to validate xpath.

Comment: Also, note, that there is a space after thousands, but you select only digits in regexp: `(r'(\d+)')`. Should be something like `(r'([\d\s]+)')`.

Comment: Share HTML source for the same. Your XPath might be wrong

Comment: <div class="product-price">
  <h3>Tarif&nbsp;:</h3> 
         <strong class="price">3 065 € HT</strong> <del>8605<!-- 3 380 --> € HT</del> forfait repas inclus,

Comment: i want only to extract the first number (3 065 €)